# Does go implements its own ssl library?

Tags: go, ssl, openssl, schannel

I need to know which ssl implementation does the compiler use. I have to build an application with ssl support and was wandering which ssl library golang relies on in each platform.
I looked around and found only [this](https://groups.google.com/g/golang-nuts/c/0za-R3wVaeQ) but since it’s quite old, I don’t know if it’s still valid.

Comment: "which ssl implementation does the compiler use" -- Why do you think the compiler uses SSL?

Comment: @Flimzy well, if the language has ssl support I think that someone has to use a ssl library (internal or external), am I wrong?

Comment: Yes, the language has SSL support. But that doesn't mean the compiler uses it. Why would any compiler use SSL?

Answer (score 6):

Go has its own implementation of TLS (not SSL though, it is long deprecated). It is provided by the [crypto/tls](https://golang.org/pkg/crypto/tls/) package of the standard library.

Answer (score 1):

> Does go implements its own ssl library?

Yes. (Well TLS.)